# Is there a way to loop this is I don't have to write it out 57 times?

Tags: java

I have a program that quotes up to 57 customizable products at one time. If there is a compatibility issue within one of the products the customer designs, an error pops up and a quote is not generated. I have it so if the generate button on line 57 is clicked, the program will check if lines 57, 56, 55... down to 1 are correct, then it will generate if they are. If line 56 is clicked, it checks 56 down to 1.

Is there a ways to loop is so that I only have to write it out once?

Here is my code:

```
if(e.getSource() == CA1.BTNgeneratequoteCA1)
     {         
        if(CA1.generateCA1 == true)
        {
           try
           {
           FillAllKIS();
           E2fill();
           FillQuote();
           }
           catch(IOException y)
           {
              Logger.severe(y.getMessage());
           }
           RecordAllLines();
        }
         }
         
   // if statments for lines 2 to 56 here

   if(e.getSource() == CA57.BTNgeneratequoteCA1)
         {         
            if(CA1.generateCA1 == true && CA2.generateCA1 == true && CA3.generateCA1 == true && CA4.generateCA1 == true && CA5.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA6.generateCA1 == true && CA7.generateCA1 == true && CA8.generateCA1 == true && CA9.generateCA1 == true && CA10.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA11.generateCA1 == true && CA12.generateCA1 == true && CA13.generateCA1 == true && CA14.generateCA1 == true && CA15.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA16.generateCA1 == true && CA17.generateCA1 == true && CA18.generateCA1 == true && CA19.generateCA1 == true && CA20.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA21.generateCA1 == true && CA22.generateCA1 == true && CA23.generateCA1 == true && CA24.generateCA1 == true && CA25.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA26.generateCA1 == true && CA27.generateCA1 == true && CA28.generateCA1 == true && CA29.generateCA1 == true && CA30.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA31.generateCA1 == true && CA32.generateCA1 == true && CA33.generateCA1 == true && CA34.generateCA1 == true && CA35.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA36.generateCA1 == true && CA37.generateCA1 == true && CA38.generateCA1 == true && CA39.generateCA1 == true && CA40.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA41.generateCA1 == true && CA42.generateCA1 == true && CA43.generateCA1 == true && CA44.generateCA1 == true && CA45.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA46.generateCA1 == true && CA47.generateCA1 == true && CA48.generateCA1 == true && CA49.generateCA1 == true && CA50.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA51.generateCA1 == true && CA52.generateCA1 == true && CA53.generateCA1 == true && CA54.generateCA1 == true && CA55.generateCA1 == true &&
               CA56.generateCA1 == true && CA57.generateCA1 == true)
            {
               try
               {
               FillAllKIS();
               E2fill();
               FillQuote();
               }
               catch(IOException y)
               {
                  Logger.severe(y.getMessage());
               }
               RecordAllLines();
            }
```

I thought about doing it with a list filled with the instances of the classes but I'm struggling to think of how the logic would work for checking the `boolean` of each line, since there is another one to check with each added line item.

Comment: Once you have them inside a list check [`allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#allMatch(java.util.function.Predicate))

Comment: What is CA1 and friends?  Can you share your declarations?  If CA1 has a type (i.e. a class), you should share that also.

Comment: But Federico has the right idea.  Make a list or array of your objects, and you can loop over that.

Comment: When you find yourself naming variables or fields with sequential numbers, think about using [collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) instead. Likely a `List` or a `Set`.

Comment: Also `if(someVariable == true)` can be simplified to `if(someVariable)`

Comment: I see the logic here is a little different. Adding the objects to a `List`, like others have suggested, is still definitely the place to start, but there's more to it than that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey CA1 - CA57 are instances of a class, It's the class that has all the attribute states for the custom product. the CA1.generate and others are booleans checking to see if there are any compatibility issues within each of the products being designed. If all are without issue, the quote is generated. I have all the CA1 - CA57 instances in a list, I've used that to loop them for other similar function, but I'm struggling with the logic at checking each generate boolean based on which # button is being clicked.

Comment: You should really rethink the design of your program. Why do you need to have those variables `CA1` to `CA57`? Get rid of them, keep track of the objects in a collection or array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
/* Create a list to hold CA1..CA57 */
List<MyClass> allCas = new ArrayList<>();
/* As you create CA1..CA57, whether in a loop or hardcoded, add them to your list, in order*/
...
allCas.add(CA1);
...
allCas.add(CA31);
...
allCas.add(CA57);

/* When button is clicked, find the related CA instance and check the preceding objects too. */
int selected = IntStream.range(0, allCas.size())
    .filter(idx -> e.getSource() == allCas.get(idx))
    .findFirst().getAsInt() + 1;
if (allCas.stream().limit(selected).allMatch(ca -> ca.generateCA1)) {
    /* Fill quote and stuff. */
    ...
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, this setup worked well